# How can i perform a POST request to LOCALHOST with PowerShell's command Invoke-WebRequest?

Tags: powershell, http, post, localhost, command-line-interface

## The problem

I want to perform a POST request to my local host using the PowerShell command "Invoke-WebRequest" but it returns an error.

## The code

This is the line of code i wrote

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Method POST -URI "http://localhost:3000/products/create"
```

## The error

This is the error that the command returns

```
Invoke-WebRequest : The response content cannot be parsed because the Internet Explorer engine is not
available, or Internet Explorer's first-launch configuration is not complete. Specify the UseBasicParsing
parameter and try again.
At line:1 char:1

+ Invoke-WebRequest -Method POST -URI "http://localhost:3000/products/c ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotImplemented: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], NotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletIEDomNotSupportedException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebR
   equestCommand
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: A post must have a body.  If you do not have a body than use GET.

Comment: Your POST is *probably* working correctly, but the error is because Internet Explorer isn't installed / available, so Windows PowerShell can't parse the response - if you add the ```-UseBasicParsing``` switch it will bypass this behaviour and will *probably* return correctly (unless there's also something else wrong with your request / response)